# how can i get value from Struts logic : iterate tag in variable

Tags: java, jsp, struts, struts-html

i am iterating a Vo in Jsp using struts  tag in which i get a integer value

```
<struts_logic:iterate id="usersVO" indexId="index" name="data" type="utils.vo.UsersVO">

<td class="tabletext"><struts_bean:write name="usersVO" property="userType"/></td>
```

here userType is a int value.
how can i get this value in

```
<%
  int x = **here**
%>
```

so i can process it for display.

Or is there any other way through which i can display String value depend upon coming int value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used struts logic:equal tag to do this and its works fine for me

```
<struts_logic:equal name="usersVO" property="userType" value="0">
   <struts_bean:message key ="usermanagement.NotAuthorization"/>                    
</struts_logic:equal>
<struts_logic:equal name="usersVO" property="userType" value="1">
   <struts_html:link page="/anzeige.do" paramId="authorization" paramName="usersVO" paramProperty="userName" style="text-decoration: none;">
      <struts_bean:message key ="usermanagement.Authorization" />
   </struts_html:link>
</struts_logic:equal>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should you `<c:choose>`. For example:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${usersVO.userType==1}">
        <p>User type is 1</p>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${usersVO.userType==2}">
        <p>etc</p>
    </c:when>
   <c:otherwise>
       <p>User type is unknown</p>
   </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```